# Why doesn't this css transition make a smooth animation from one point to the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to transition an element (image) to the center of the page.

The problem is that it jumps to one point and then animates the rest of the transitions instead of animating one movement to the center.

```
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.transformed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here you can see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/xz8o225yz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must enter the parameters in the first class as well. 
like:

```
    img {
      position: relative;
      width: 350px;
      left: 0; 
      top: 0;
      transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: .5s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
    }

    .transformed {
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Only if you add ex: **left:0** and **top:0** the animation know where have to start. The same for all parameters you want animated.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have not defined the value for `left` and `top` properties which you have defined in `.transformed` selector. Try this code.

```
img {
            position: relative;
            width: 350px;
            transition-property: all;
            transition-duration: .5s;
            transition-timing-function: ease;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementById('myImg');
  el.classList.add("transformed");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  /* added; or on any other parent element */
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  position: absolute; /* modified */
  top: 25px; /* added */
  left: 0; /* added */
  width: 350px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.transformed {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Center</button>
<img id="myImg" src="https://media0.giphy.com/media/JIX9t2j0ZTN9S/giphy.gif">
```